# rails decode json cyrrilic string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, encoding

I have such string example, which i get from json (cp1251):

```
Ôèëüòð ìàñëÿíûé OPEL/GM/DAEWOO
```

which mean:

```
Фильтр масляный OPEL/GM/DAEWOO
```

this tool http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/  say that i must use CP1252 → CP1251 decoder. I try it so:

```
my_string.force_encoding('cp1252').force_encoding('1251')
```

but it didn't solve my problem. What i do wrong?

how could i convert to normall view my json cyrrillic string in RoR?

i get json from url so:

```
jsonAE = JSON.load(open('http://******/portal.api?l=*****&p=Sih2*****&act=price_by_nr_firm&nr='+article_nr+'&oe=true'))
```

from json i get:

```
{"result":[{"nr":"OC90","brand":"Knecht","name":"Фильтр масляный OPEL/GM/DAEWOO","stock":"-","delivery":"не известно","minq":"1","upd":"16.03.15 23:40","price":"130.34","currency":"руб."},{"nr":"OC90","brand":"Knecht","name":‌​"Фильтр масляный OPEL/GM/DAEWOO","stock":"-","delivery":"не известно","minq":"1","upd":"17.03.15 00:05","price":"130.34","currency":"руб."}]}
```

but it turn's to something bad with `JSON.load`

Comment: Requires URL to reproduce problem.

Comment: Or just download it use CURL and save to file (it shouldn't broke initial encoding).

Comment: @maxd i could send it to your just via pm somehow... on email maybe?

Comment: @maxd how to code it?

Comment: @maxd Everything you need to reproduce the problem is a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
▶ puts 'Ôèëüòð ìàñëÿíûé OPEL/GM/DAEWOO'
        .encode(Encoding::CP1252)
        .force_encoding(Encoding::CP1251)
        .encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
#⇒ Фильтр масляный OPEL/GM/DAEWOO
```

The string in ruby is suspected to be `utf8`ed. So, the first action is to inform ruby that the string is actually in one-byte. Than we say “hey, don’t care, I know this one-byte is actually cyrillic.” And, finally, turn it back to utf-8.

Hope it helps.

Comment: U+0424 to WINDOWS-1252 in conversion from UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1252

Comment: `U+0424` is by no means one-byte. It is [valid unicode “Ф”](http://unicode-table.com/ru/search/?q=U%2B0424). Since you receive some garbage in the json, you might want to handle it accurately, not by forcing encoding.

Comment: I have no clue what do you actually receive. Whether it might occasionally be both utf8 and/or cp1251, I would go with try-catch encoding to one-byte as I have shown above. Unless it fails, what means you already have a valid utf8.

Comment: i recieve error  `U+0424 to WINDOWS-1252 in conversion from UTF-8 to WINDOWS-1252`

Comment: don't be so rude. i just noticed that you solution didn't work. i think you will be downvoted with time, not by me.

Comment: @mudasobwa i think op mean that your solution didn't work even that it is utf8 already

Comment: Please go read [ho to ask the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). My solution perfectly works _for the question you originally posted_. It converts the string you provided as an example to the string you have supplied as an expected result. This is how SO works. Whether you have another question, ask it separately.

Comment: @PavelBY Of course it does not. Furthermore, it should not, since it’s a solution for the specific question OP posted. Even more, I spent time and answer here in comments on how to handle utf8 case.